# How to use queryset with distinct to avoid duplication value in label_from_instance?

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I want to use `queryset` with `distinct()` to avoid duplication value in `label_from_instance`.

But then I have an error like below.

> 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

How could I use `queryset` with `distinct()` in `label_from_instance`?

---

Here are the code in forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField


class NameChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return f'{obj.name}'
        

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    code = NameChoiceField(queryset=MyModel.objects.all().values_list('name',flat=True).order_by('name').distinct())
```

---

python 3.8

Django 3.2

Mysql 5.7

Comment: There are multiple `MyModel`s with the same name? This seems to me like the main problem, you should prevent that.

Comment: Remove `values_list('name',flat=True)` it seems this is passing a string into the label_from_instance rather than the object itself perhaps?  Also not sure why you need distinct in this query, it isn't doing any joins for the dataset to return duplicates?

Comment: @Artisan, If I try removing this code`values_list('name',flat=True)`, I don't catch the error, but the form shows a label with the same value.

Comment: @Tio: yes, and that is because multiple `MyModel`s have the same `name`. It does not make any sense to use a `.distinct()`. Imagine that a user selects Foo, then which Foo will it use? There can be a lot of duplicates. That is why the essence of the problem is that you allow that there are multiple `MyModel`s with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could I use queryset with `distinct()` in label_from_instance?

You **don't**. Imagine that you use `.distinct()` and thus got unique names and a person selects an option "foo", if there are multiple `MyModel`s with "foo" as name, then which one should be selected: by making a distinct, you thus "destroy" the way to backlink to the original item. The label should be sufficient to *canonically* specify what model item to use.

You should fix the problem at the other end: preventing that one can use multiple `MyModel`s with the same `name`, you can mark the `name` field as unique and thus work with:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    # …
```

It is also possible that items should be unique *per user* for example. In that case you construct a [**`UniqueConstraint`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) with:

```
from django.conf import settings

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=('name', 'user'), name='unique_name_per_user')
        ]
```

In that case you filter the queryset in the form with the `user` with:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    code = NameChoiceField(queryset=MyModel.objects.order_by('name'))

    def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            self.field['code'].queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(
                user=user
            ).order_by('name')
```

where you then construct the `MyModelForm` with `MyModelForm(user=request.user)` for example.